# Deploy next js in heroku

Tags: reactjs, heroku, next.js

I'm using this code in package.json and I want to deploy to heroku app

> "scripts": {
>       "build": "cd app && next build",
>       "start": "npm run build && env NODE_ENV=production node app.js",
>       "dev": "nodemon --ignore app/ app.js"    },

I have also tried:

> "start": "next start -p $PORT", I'm using this boilerplate:
>   https://github.com/MustansirZia/next-express-bootstrap-boilerplate

currently im getting this...

> test.herokuapp.com/_next/static/VprFLaLvekNmzlVsEkO_S/pages/… and it
>   shows a loading of page... and doesnt show the index
>
> i had var port = process.env.PORT || 3000; "start": "npm run build &&
>   env NODE_ENV=production node app.js -p $PORT ",

i ran

> npm run start
>
> > next-express-bootstrap-boilerplate@0.1.1 start /Users/carlosmanuelmouravieira/Desktop/projects/frontend/learn
> >     npm run build && env NODE_ENV=production node app.js -p $PORT
> >
> > next-express-bootstrap-boilerplate@0.1.1 build /Users/carlosmanuelmouravieira/Desktop/projects/frontend/learn
> >     cd app && next build
>
> Creating an optimized production build ...
>
> > Using external babel configuration
> >     Location: "/Users/carlosmanuelmouravieira/Desktop/projects/frontend/learn/app/.babelrc"
> >     Compiled successfully.
>
> ┌ /_app  ├ /_document  ├ /_error  ├ /box/main  ├ /box/suggestions  ├
>   /dashboard/dashboard  ├ /employee/login  ├ /employee/main  ├
>   /getPageContext  ├ /ideas/main  ├ /ideas/suggestions  ├ /index  ├
>   /index.1  ├ /index/data  ├ /main/main  └ /post

Answer (score 4):

as @monday answer very well but now  `heroku-postbuild` script entry is no longer required because heroku now automatically running `npm run build` .

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start -p $PORT"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The post is six months old but hopefully, I will be able to save someone 2min of searching the internet because of this problem.
your script should look like this

`"scripts": {
  "dev": "next",
  "build": "next build",
  "start": "next start -p $PORT",
  "heroku-postbuild": "npm run build",
  "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
},`

**Push to GitHub**

```
$ git init
$ git add .
$ git commit -m "First Commit"
$ git remote add origin https://github.com/{username}/{repositoryname}
$ git push origin master
```

**Create Heroku app**

```
$ heroku create my-app
```

**Deploy on Heroku**

- Open your browser and sign into Heroku
- Navigate to the “Dashboard”
- Select your newly created app
- Click “Deploy”
- Under “Deployment Method” select “Github”
- Add repository name ({username}/{repositoryname})
- Click “Search”
- Click “Connect”
- Select Branch
- Click “Deploy Branch”
- Click “View”

you can read the entire article by 
[Jacob Oakley](https://medium.com/@jacoboakley/deploy-a-next-js-app-on-heroku-69bcb01db1b7)

Comment: The build succeed but when deployed I got "sh: next command not found"

Comment: It would have been more helpful if I saw your error log. However, a couple of things you can check, Make sure you don't have `package-lock.json` and `yarn-lock.json` in the project (you can do away with one), I had that problem once and it was cause by my node version which i update and everything worked very well. if none of the aforementioned works for you consider adding a little more clue (error log will be fine). #cheers

Comment: All that is well and nice,but what to do with ENV variables?

Answer (score 0):

May be it is too late but like @Monday just said, you can do that and update the build command like this to avoid the sh:next command not found error

```
"build": "npm i && npm run build"
```